# UIScrollView contentSize doesn't work

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have a problem with my UIScollView who scrolls vertically. I just want my ScollView scroll horizontally. I've tried to change the contentSize but that doesn't worked.

I use constraints, and this code :

```
var plugeeNews : [Plugs]?

var topNewsScrollView : UIScrollView = {
        var scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 75))
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .gray
        scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()


func setupViewInTopNewsScrollView() {
        for i in 0..<plugeeNews.count {
            let xPosition = screenSize.width * CGFloat(i)
            let myView = TopNewsCell(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: screenSize.width , height: heightOfNewsCell))
            myView.label.text = plugeeNews[i]
            myView.randomBackgroundColor(number: i)
            topNewsScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: topNewsScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1),height:  heightOfNewsCell)
            topNewsScrollView.addSubview(myView)
        }
    }
```

This is the height constraint of my UIScrollView :

```
...
        topNewsScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightOfNewsCell).isActive = true
```

And this is the result :

[image]

And I don't want the gray view below the white/gray views on the UIScollView, i just want to swipe between my views horizontally.

Comment: Why are you setting the `contentSize` of your `UIScrollView` each time you add a new `UIView` ??

Comment: You should read carefully this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial

Comment: Victor : it's to avoid to create a new variable to save the `i` value. Ah ok I'm going to read the tutorial, thanks

Comment: The `contentSize` should be assigned only once  not every time as you're doing in the above code

Answer (score -1):

Set the content size:

```
scrollContainer.contentSize = CGSize(width:10000, height:50)
```

Comment: If you set the `width` to `10000` of course it will scroll horizontally, but this need to be calculated properly in base of the number of `UIView`s inside the `UIScrollView` and not set manually in this way

Comment: Ok i'm going to try this, but why do i must put 50 instead of the height of my content view ( who is 100 )

Comment: That doesn't worked, i always can move my cell vertically, and it's not centered.